# Parse push Notification android. working on Console(DashBoard)- not working on Device

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have an App in android with push notification, using Parse.

Push notification perfectly works through DashBoard

But not work if I use code from mobile:

```
ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
push.setChannel("Ch1");
push.setMessage(message);
push.sendInBackground();
```